# Spring optional parameter int

Tags: java, spring

I have a method in Spring controller like this;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public final ModelAndView contact(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) int i)  {..}
```

I pass in the parameter i to another method. In that method, I want to check if there is a value in int i. If the parameter was not set (this is optional), I want to set it to a certain value. How do I check this in Spring?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `Integer` instead of `int`. If it's not set, it will be null.

If, for example, 0 is not a valid ID value, you can also leave the type as `int` and use

```
@RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "0")
```

The parameter will than be equal to 0 if not passed.